# Compile-time variables in webpack, is NODE_ENV special?

Tags: node.js, webpack

I'm using webpack 4.41.6.

If I have this in one of my JS files:

```js
const var1 = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? 'foo' : 'bar';
const var2 = process.env.SOME_VAR === 'something' ? 'moo' : 'cow';

console.log(var1, var2);
```

Then run `SOME_VAR=something NODE_ENV=production webpack`, I get:

```js
a="something"===e.env.SOME_VAR?"moo":"cow";console.log("bar",a);
```

What is special about NODE_ENV?
How can I get the same compile-time optimization with SOME_VAR?

Thanks for any help with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got some help from the [webpack gitter](https://gitter.im/webpack/webpack); they pointed me in the direction of [DefinePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/) and [Mode](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/mode/).

It turns out that `NODE_ENV` *is* special, it causes something like this to be generated:

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({ "process.env.NODE_ENV": JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV) })
```

I had overlooked this because I did not have DefinePlugin in my webpack configuration or node dependencies; apparently it is built-in?

I added this to my webpack config and it now works as I hoped:

```
plugins.push(
  new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV),
    'process.env.SOME_VAR': JSON.stringify(process.env.SOME_VAR)
  })
);
```